# ClassNotFoundException while deploying app in jboss

Tags: deployment, jboss, classnotfoundexception, noclassdeffounderror

I am first time using jboss to deploye app and stuck in ClassNotFoundException although jar is present in WEB-INF lib folder, any thought

```
01:02:32,221 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."abc.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."abc.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "abc.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018757: Error getting reflective information for class security.filter.SecurityFilter with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.abc.war:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:72) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:92)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: **LXYALogger**;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:68) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: **XYALogger** from [Module "deployment.abc.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:196) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:444) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:432) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:399) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:374) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:119) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]

... 15 more
```

Comment: Are you sure the class LXYALogger is available in your war file ?

Comment: @ehsavoie class name is **XYALogger** but it is expecting **LXYALogger** and I am not referencing  **LXYALogger** anywhere.

Comment: My understanding is that XYALogger is referencing  LXYALogger